# Is there a way to hide Grizzly server version when displaying error pages?

Tags: grizzly

Is there a way to hide Grizzly server version when displaying error pages for security reasons. Also could you point me document for configuring Grizzly server. Not able to find from https://grizzly.java.net.

Grizzly server version: 2.3.16.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please do the following:

```
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().setHttpServerVersion("");
```

Comment: is there any document to understand Grizzly, if so can you please share it.

Comment: It's on the grizzly.java.net, drop down menu in the top right corner.